# Angular 2 + RxJS: async pipe with .share() operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

When using the `async` pipe on a observable that is using the `.share()` operator (due to expensive calculations in the backend), I stumbled upon this behaviour:

```
data$ = (new Observable(observer => {
    let counter=0;
    observer.next(counter)

    window.setInterval(() => {
      observer.next(counter);
      counter++;
    }, 2000);
  }))
  .share();
```

Template:

```
{{ (data$|async) !== null }}
{{ (data$|async) !== null }}
```

The output of the initial value is:

```
true false
```

The following outputs (after more than 2 seconds) are:

```
true true
```

which is the behavior I would expect for the first value, too.
If I omit the `.share()`, the output for the first value is `"true true"`, as I would expect. I suppose the behavior above is due to the fact that the first expression in the template triggers observable execution, and once the second `async` pipe subscribes to the observable, the data is already gone. Is this explanation correct? And how can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Since there is supposed to be a single value, it is `observer.next(...); observer.complete()`.

Comment: the example with a single value was just for demonstration, in my app the observable has multiple values

Comment: Please, provide the code that reflects your case then.

Comment: I edited my question with an example code: The first value of the observable triggers the strange behavior, while the later ones don't. Do you maybe know a way to make the first value available for both async pipes?

Comment: I guess I do. In RxJS4 `shareReplay(1)` was used (as the name says, it shares the replay of last 1 value). For A2+RxJS5 a direct counterpart can be used, see the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [the reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html),

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted.

In RxJS 4, `shareReplay` is used to achieve the desired behaviour.

In RxJS 5, a direct counterpart to `shareReplay` is `publishReplay` followed by `refCount` ([see the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246873/sharereplay-in-rxjs-5) and [the discussion](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/453)).

So it should be

```
data$ = (new Observable(observer => { ... }))
.publishReplay(1)
.refCount();
```

Comment: But why did it show true and then false ? ( at time=0)

Comment: Because at time 0 data$ contains one value (`0`), and after subscription with first `(data$|async)` it's 'exhausted'. Since there is no second value in data$, and `(data$|async)` expression should resolve to some value synchronously, it resolves to `null` (this is how `async` pipe works).

Comment: Wait , at time=0 , how many subscribers exists ?1 or 2 ? ( i'm asking it becuase share sees refcounts. ). Can you please explain this in a refcount POV ?

Comment: `{{ (data$|async) !== null }} {{ (data$|async) !== null }}` creates 2 subscriptions, and for shared observable there are 2 refcounts.

Comment: estus , I know this but what happens for non-shared observable ? this is what i'm trying to understand  - how come the first is getting true while the second one also subscribed , which means refcount=2 ... ?

Comment: In non-shared observable, `observer => { ... }` is called every time data$ is subscribed, and each subscription gets a value that is produced with `observer.next(0)`. In shared observable, it's called once, and the value gets the first subscription. I'd suggest to stay away from async and true/false, because they make things more complicated. Try `data$.subscribe(console.log); data$.subscribe(console.log)` on shared observable and you'll see that only 1 log entry is produced, by first subscription.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. ^^

Comment: I've tried what you said and it's logged twice : http://jsbin.com/bayibopazi/edit?js,console

Comment: Glad if it helped. That's because you used Observable.of, it produces completed observable. It will be different for `new Observable(o => o.next(1))`, http://jsbin.com/gexijovose/1/edit?js,console

Comment: estos - I've asked a new question ( to not pollute this thread)  : it seems that I'm still missing something : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561125/rxjss-share-operator-behaves-differently-when-complete

Comment: @RoyiNamir I'll look into it, but it seems that you summed it up well. Observables are automatically unsubscribed on completion, that's the point. There are some RxJS guys on SO who can possibly explain this better than I did.

Comment: What about RxJS 6? There is still (or again?) `shareReplay()`. And this blog post says it's also part of RxJS 5.4 ( https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-whats-changed-with-sharereplay-65c098843e95 ). Or is this something different than version 4's `shareReplay()`?

Comment: @BenjaminM Indeed, and the link you posted does a good job at explaining that. I suppose it should be used as [this example](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cartant/1b45497bbb560ea2d9552ce2d3e3421d/raw/795df7476c51b85a22cf9951ef4e20b9d96f1f91/share-replay-interval-ref-count.ts) shows, `shareReplay({
  bufferSize: 1,
  refCount: true
})` because default options result in different behaviour. It doesn't seem more expressive than `.publishReplay(1).refCount()` to me.