# Sharing Auth Observable value between components without executing it multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable, subject

I have an `AuthService` that fetch an `Observable<auth>` data from Firebase and put it in a public variable `auth$`.

Somewhere in my app, I need multiple components to access this `auth$` value to check its content.

I'm currently just doing `this.authService.auth$.subscribe(auth => this.auth = auth)` in components.

1. **Does it mean that I'm executing the `fetch data from Firebase` multiple times?**
2. **If yes, should I define auth$ as a Subject/BehaviorSubject, subscribe in the service and push data with `.next`?**

Comment: FIrebase has some internal caching, so it shouldn't be a problem. You can check network traffic in DevTools > Network > WebSockets...

Comment: OK that's good to know about Firebase, I'll check this out. But what about an http call? (something without caching)

Comment: You can use [`share()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share) operator, `this.authService.auth$ = Observable.of('whatever').share()` and it should be shared among all subscriptions...

Comment: Ok cool thanks for your answer.

Comment: Any update on this. I have another thread looking into this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755912/how-to-easily-convert-or-assign-an-observable-to-a-behavior-subject-so-other-co
I use behavior subject for the firebase auth so it's multicast enabled. But now I want the userInfo to be multicast enabled but I have no idea how to reproduce the same pattern - sharing data across my angular 2 app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default an observable is not multicast enabled. This means that multiple subscriptions will generate their own stream. Since you do not want to have to re-fetch the authentication credentials per subscription you need to make your original stream multicast-compatible. This is done using  for example the `share()` operator, which will make the stream hot upon the first subscription and internally stores a refcount for all following subscriptions.

Since subscriptions which are late to the party will not automatically get the previous emitted values when the stream became hot we need to build in functionality to replay emitted values.

Both of these requirements are combined in the [`shareReplay()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sharereplay.md) operator which lets your multicast the latest *n* values.

So your code would look like this:

```
const authStream = this.authService.auth$.shareReplay(1);

// component 1
const myAuthDisposable = authStream.subscribe(auth => this.auth = auth)

// component 2
const myAuthDisposable = authStream.subscribe(auth => this.auth = auth)
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I didn't know `shareReplay()`. It seems like it has been removed. It's saying [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246873/sharereplay-in-rxjs-5) that it should be replaced with `.publishReplay(1).refCount()`. Do you agree?

Comment: The long discussion in the github issue seems to say that `.publishReplay(1)` behaviour will be the same in rxjs5 as in rxjs4 so using in combined with `refCount()` would seem to work. Have not tested it myself though.